# TypeError: list indices must be integers in Tic Tac Toe game - Python 3.2?

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror, tic-tac-toe

so i've had multiple problems with a tic tac toe game i'm making, but i've found solutions to most of the problems. but the problem now is that i get an error reading

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/tic tac toe game.py", line 43, in <module>
    if board[input] != 'x' and board[input] !='o':
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not builtin_function_or_method"
```

when i try and run it. and here's the code it's having issues with:

```
if board[input] != 'x' and board[input] !='o':
        board[input] = 'x'
```

i'm not sure what to do and i like just started python on thursday and am not very smart with it.. but thanks for all the help (: oh and i have python 3.2.

Comment: a case of bad variable names i think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like `input` is not an integer here, you've used `input()` here, which is a built-in function.
Don't ever use `input` as a variable name too.

**see same error:**

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4]
>>> a[input]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    a[input]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not builtin_function_or_method
```

to work around it, use:

```
>>> Board=['a','x','o','b','c','d']
>>> n=input()#input returns a string,not integer
2
>>> if Board[int(n)]!='x' and Board[int(n)]!='o': #list expect  only integer indexes,convert n to integer first using
    Board[int(n)]='x'


>>> Board
['a', 'x', 'o', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: k.. but now it says "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/tic tac toe game.py", line 43, in <module>
    if Board[int(n)]!='x' and Board[int(n)]!='o':
NameError: name 'Board' is not defined"

Comment: and i decided to change "Board" to "board" and that error was gone & and then it came up with this error -_- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/tic tac toe game.py", line 43, in <module>
    if board[int(n)]!='x' and board[int(n)]!='o':
NameError: name 'n' is not defined

Comment: @AliLewis I just used an example code here coz I don't know how your code looks like and which variable you've defined.I've used some variables which might not be present in your code(such as `n`).

Comment: i'm confused.. i just need to find the new code and fix it. i'm like dying to get this game finished ):

Comment: Every error you're getting is fundamentally the same. Please learn to *read the error message* and cross-reference carefully with your own code. You cannot write `int(n)` without first explaining what `n` is. `N` is not the same. Similarly `board` and `Board`.